# CSS Style for ModelState.AddFormError("Unable to login")

Tags: webmatrix, modelstate

i want to style my error message which is "unable to login" but i dont know how to tag it in css? thanks in advance. 
im using webmatrix 2.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you have a code to show. but i will imagine you mearnt injecting css to a failed login.

```
if(!Validation.IsValid()){
  <style type="text/css">
      /*Style the error class here */
  </style>
}
```